# scaffoldで生成されるjavascriptなどの出力先や中身をカスタマイズする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

javascriptとstylesheetの出力先とファイル名と中身をカスタマイズするにはどうすればいいですか？

出力先は以下のように変えたいです。

app/assets/javascripts/items.js
↓
app/javascript/packs/items/[index show new edit].js

app/assets/stylesheets/moves.css
↓
app/javascript/app-styles/items/[index show new edit].sass

Answer (score 1):

ファイルの中身の変更だけであれば簡単です。

```
rails app:templates:copy
(Rails ５以前だとrake rails:templates:copy)
```

すると、lib/templatesにテンプレートのファイルがコピーされますのでこれを編集してください。

出力先を書き換えるのは少々大変です。ジェネレータの動作をカスタマイズする必要があります。仕組みは用意されていますが、一から手順を説明するのは少々大変なので、[Rails guide](https://railsguides.jp/generators.html)を参照してください。

方針は２つ考えられます。

- ジェネレータそのものを置き換える
- 一旦オリジナルのジェネレータを動かした後に、ファイルをコピー・移動・書き換えるジェネレータを動かす